# okta login success but redirect the page not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, okta-api

Getting Okta api success but inside of this success function redirect its not working, alert also not working. May you please let me know where my mistake is?

```
var oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
        authParams: {
            responseType: 'id_token',
            responseMode: 'okta_post_message',
            scopes: ['openid', 'groups'],
           // data : JSON.stringify(data1)
        },
        clientId: OKTA_CLIENT_ID,
        baseUrl: OKTA_ORG_URL,
        //redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080",

    });
    oktaSignIn.renderEl(
        { el: '#okta-login-container' },
        function (res) {
            if (res.status == 'SUCCESS') {
                alert("User successfully authenticated");
                console.log(res);

                //$window.location.href = 'main.jsp';
            /* if (res.claims.groups.includes('Example')) {
                    console.log("User in 'Example' group");
                    // Uncomment the line below to redirect to example.com
                    // window.location = "http://www.example.com";
                }*/
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: What's you `res` coming? Tried logging it?

Comment: above the same code i have tried res success after success i need to redirect so can you check it ?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, If `res.status == 'SUCCESS'` is itself failing then it is natural for the alert and the redirection code not to work. You can use `$location.path("https://www.google.com/");` to redirect to a url in AngularJs